# Copying styled text from a page to the clipboard with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

I've created a simple tool so employees can personalize their company email signature. This tool creates some styled text with some bolded fonts and a bit of color, nothing fancy. If I then select the text and copy and paste it into my Gmail signature field all works well. It retains the formatting. However, I'd prefer to give the user the option of clicking a "Copy" button that copies the formatted content onto their clipboard.

I'm currently using ZeroClipboard to add the "copy to clipboard" functionality and it's working great. Thing is I don't know how to grab that formatted text. It just keeps copying the unformatted version. One thing I tried was adding a mouseDown listener to ZeroClipboard that selects the text like this:

```
function selectText() {
    if (document.selection) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById('clicktocopy'));
        range.select();
    }
    else if (window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(document.getElementById('clicktocopy'));
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    }
}
```

Then returns the selection like this:

```
function getText() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var range = window.getSelection();
        return range.toString();
    }
    else {
        if (document.selection.createRange) {
            var range = document.selection.createRange();
            return range.text;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is only copying the unformatted text. Is it possible to copy the text formatted?

My formatted text is in a div with the id "results".

Comment: How are you applying the styles? Inline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an HTML string representing the current selection, the following function will do this (replacing your `getText()` function):

```
function getSelectionHtml() {
    var html = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }
    return html;
}
```

Comment: It's strange. The first time I ran this it copied the formatted text. When I pasted into my email program it looked exactly the same. Now, and every other time, it's actually copying the HTML. Nothing changed, though. Not sure what happened.

Comment: I have a very similar solution, but I've noticed that if you select text in the middle of a bold section, for instance, the text doesn't keep the formatting.  Any idea how to include those tags, too?  (Side note: if you select across a formatting boundary, it automatically closes the tags, by the way.)