# Copying from clipboard using ZeroClipboard: want to get formatted text

Tags: javascript, zeroclipboard

I'm copying some text to the clipboard using JS: [ZeroClipboard](http://davidwalsh.name/clipboard). This text which I'm copying is inside a `<div>` tag, and contains HTML formatting. It's working, but when I'm copying the text, the HTML tags get copied as they are! What I want is something on the client side that gives me formatted text, and I'm currently getting unformatted text. Please help!

Code:

```
var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
clip.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
        clip.setText(document.getElementById('oSource').innerText);
    });

    clip.addEventListener('complete', function (client, text) {
        alert('copied: ' + text);
    });

    //glue it to the button
    clip.glue('Button1');
    clip.glue('Button2');
```

I know it's similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084713/copying-styled-text-from-a-page-to-the-clipboard-with-javascript), but here he's used createTextRange,not ZeroClipBoard

Comment: The other question is also using ZeroClipboard. The question is just about getting the data to add to the clipboard, and his solution should work for you just as well. But I'm not really sure what you want can be done; formatting is part of rendering HTML to the window, JavaScript doesn't have a notion of formatted text independent of rendering it.

Comment: if it using clipboard, why is it using createTextRange()?? In the link I've posted for ZeroClipboard, nothing of the sort has been used

Comment: He's using `createTextRange()` to get the selection to copy to the clipboard. He doesn't show the code that copies to the clipboard, that's in the caller of `getText()`.

Comment: yes, but that createTextRange doesn't work with any other browser except IE. That's the point of using ZeroClipBoard

Comment: Are you also using JQuery? Instead of using the alert command above, what happens if you do something like `$("#existingdiv").html("copied:"+text);` assuming there is a div with an id 'existingdiv' in your html.

Comment: @mccannf: I did that...and the text got copied with the formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the flash file Zeroclipboard10.swf for it to copy rich text. It worked when I added this line.

```
ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath("ZeroClipboard10.swf");
```

Comment: FYI see http://170.140.138.214/zctests/ZeroClipboard-1.0.7/test_ZC-1.0.7.html; at the moment this file is available from http://170.140.138.214/zctests/ZeroClipboard-1.0.7/ZeroClipboard10.swf